# datesub question

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to use date_sub like this ?

```
$dt = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`date`) VALUES ('DATE_SUB('$dt', INTERVAL 15 DAY)')";

$result = MYSQL_QUERY($query);
```

Thanks

Comment: just run this and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use it on database by removing the quotes around `DATE_SUB(...)`.
But you should consider using the unix time stamp with time() and reconverting it to a date format using the date() function, like this:

```
$dt = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time() - 15*24*3600); //today - 15 days
```

Works with PHP 4 and PHP 5.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you not to leave calendar calculations to the database. Use the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead and have the [timezonedb](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) extension updated. This is actually one those things PHP gets right.

See also [this post](http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html) on Derick's blog.

Comment: doesnt datetime require php 3.0 ?

Comment: You probably ment 5.3 - answer: no, all the necessary functionality is in 5.2

Comment: oh sorry i meant 5.3 ok, can you show a sample code ? and what if i have to do that on database ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong `'DATE_SUB('$dt', INTERVAL 15 DAY)'`, that's a string.

Now, your date format is same as the format used by MySQL's `NOW()` function.

```
SELECT NOW();
---------------------
|now()              |
---------------------
|2010-05-15 20:42:35|
---------------------
```

And since I've been using without any problem `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);` in a recent project, I don't see any reason why you could not use it.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 6 MONTH );
-----------------------------------
|DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)|
-----------------------------------
|2009-11-15 20:49:28              |
-----------------------------------
```